# Need to retrieve form data

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, passport.js

I have some login page, as soon as the authenticated get success, in the next page, I should display Login Details.. ( ie., username and password )

I'm using Express NodeJs, Passport, connect-flash, mongoose

**My prob is:** I'm unable to understand how to retrieve username, password in the next rendered page..

Please someone suggest me how to achieve it. I'm not asking you code, BUT show me a way to get my output.

**EDIT**:

**app.js**

```
 var http = require('http');
var express =  require('express'),
    passport = require('passport')
    , LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy,
    flash = require('connect-flash'),
    User = require('./routes/userdao.js');


passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    function(username, password, done) {
        User.findOne({ uname: username ,pwd:password}, function(err, user) {
            if (err) { return done(err); }
            if (!user) {
                return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
            }
            return done(null, user);
        });
    }
));


passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user._id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});


var app = express();


app.configure(function(){
    app.use(express.logger('dev'));     /* 'default', 'short', 'tiny', 'dev' */
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.session({ secret: 'mysecret' }));
    app.use(flash());
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());
    app.engine('.html', require('ejs').__express);
    app.set('view engine', 'html');
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.use(app.router);
    // app.use(express.errorHandler());

}).listen(3000);

console.log('Listening on port 3000...');
app.get('/',function(req,res){
  /*  req.flash('info', 'Flash is back!')
    res.redirect('/success');*/
    res.render('home.ejs');
});

app.get('/login',function(req,res){
    res.render('login.ejs');
});

app.get('/success',function(req,res){
    res.render('success.ejs',{ uname : req.user.username });
});

app.post('/login',
    passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/success', failureRedirect: '/login',
        failureFlash: true  }));
```

**success.ejs**

```
<%= uname %>
```

I'm trying to display username which I entered in the login page.. I'm getting output: `undefined`

**please tell me what went wrong and what I need to correct?**

Comment: Can you add any of the session middleware you may be using and how you've configured Passport middleware.  Check out this link http://passportjs.org/guide/configure/ especially the sections on Middleware and Sessions.  Assuming you are intending to use sessions to store logged in data you need to tell Passport how to do that.

Comment: @MattPileggi I added FULL code, could you please check now!

Comment: Thanks.  And just to get the simple question out of the way:  are you sure your req.user object has a property 'username'?  When you are doing findOne you are querying { uname: username } so I'm assuming you should be setting { uname: req.user.uname } for your view.

Comment: @MattPileggi HI bro, username and password  values will get from login form when submitted! so, it means values getting from request only!

Comment: Inside of your /success handler, since it is a redirect, req.user will be the object that you serialize/deserialize.  So req.user.username would be undefined unless your user object had { username: 'Bob' }, while it appears that your data model actually has { uname: 'Bob' }

Answer (score 0):

In the most general sense, if authentication succeeds the user object you return from authenticate ends up at `req.user` in your downstream functions.

http://passportjs.org/guide/authenticate/

And then, assuming you are using sessions, any subsequent requests will also expose `req.user` based on your serializeUser/deserializeUser functions.

Comment: can you please tell me how to forward 'req.user' to the next rendered page?

Comment: Passport does this automatically with sessions.  You should have already configured passport.serializeUser(function(user,done) { ... }) and passport.deserializeUser(function(id,req,done) { ... })  That is how Passport stores a string in the session and the reconstitutes a User object each request.  If you want to add that code to your question you may be able to get a more specific answer based on what you are doing there.

Comment: Could you please check my Edited answer in my first Post.. I added some code there... please check and tell me what I have to do..